# how can I store ssh keys without a home directory?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to log into a remote computer `remoteB` from another server, `remoteA`, but I do not want to enter my password for `remoteB` every time. I want to create SSH keys to do this, but the problem is that I do not have a home directory on `remoteA`, only on `remoteB`.

I tried creating a directory `.ssh` inside a (non-home) directory on A to which I have access, but when I do

```
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub username@remoteB
```

then it returns the error

```
Could not create directory '/home/name/.ssh'
The authenticity of host 'remoteB' can't be established
```

This makes sense, since I don't have a directory in `/home/` on `remoteA`. But is there a way to either use a folder other than my home-directory for my SSH keys instead?

Comment: you might try fooling it with `mkdir temp; cd temp; export HOME=$PWD` and then running ssh-copy-id.  I've got around similar issues by pretending PWD is HOME, just for the duration of one task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message `Could not create directory '/home/test3/.ssh'.` is a warning, not an error. You can store your `ssh` keys anywhere secure, but the default would be your home directory.

Example, where local user `test3` has no home directory and user `test4@otherhost` does have a home directory. Start by being logged in locally as user test3:

Create "secure" directory and generate certificate pair

```
mkdir -m700 /tmp/ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /tmp/ssh/id_rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
...
Your public key has been saved in /tmp/ssh/id_rsa.pub.
...
```

Attempt to copy it to destination

```
ssh-copy-id -i /tmp/ssh/id_rsa.pub test4@otherhost
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: 59: cd: can't cd to /home/test3
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/tmp/ssh/id_rsa.pub"
The authenticity of host 'otherhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:pqNd/9gP69W2hzcosj+GI2DY2uw3+Upvvg22KV8sq5A.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
mktemp: failed to create file via template ‘/home/test3/.ssh/ssh-copy-id_id.XXXXXXXXXX’: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: mktemp failed
```

Notice at this point *the installation has failed*, so we need to revert to the equivalent manual process. We'll put the `known_hosts` file somewhere safe, too, to stop `ssh` complaining each time it's used

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/ssh/known_hosts test@otherhost 'mkdir -m700 -p .ssh && cat >>.ssh/authorized_keys' </tmp/ssh/id_rsa.pub
Could not create directory '/home/test3/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'otherhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:pqNd/9gP69W2hzcosj+GI2DY2uw3+Upvvg22KV8sq5A.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'otherhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
```

There are lots of warnings here but fundamentally the process has worked, and the key is now in the remote account's `authorized_keys` file. Let's test it

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/ssh/known_hosts -i /tmp/ssh/id_rsa test4@otherhost date
Could not create directory '/home/test3/.ssh'.
Thu 26 Nov 10:16:23 GMT 2020
```

We got a date string back from the remote host, so we can demonstrate it's all worked.

Caveat: each time you use `ssh` you must explicitly define the `known_hosts` file as well as the `id_rsa` secret

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/tmp/ssh/known_hosts -i /tmp/ssh/id_rsa ...
```